# В каких случаях сложные прилагательные пишутся через дефис, а в каких слитно?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, прилагательные

В каких случаях сложные прилагательные пишутся через дефис, а в каких слитно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще говоря, это сложная тема, и в некоторых случаях приходится проверять свое решение по словарю.

Тем не менее ОСНОВНАЯ ЧАСТЬ написаний соответствует следующему правилу: слитно пишутся сложные прилагательные, образованные на основе сочетания с подчинительной связью, а через дефис пишутся сложные прилагательные, составленные из основ двух прилагательных.

Например: белоствольная береза (белый ствол), бело-голубой флаг (белый и голубой, однородное сочинение основ), бледно-голубое небо (голубое бледного оттенка, неоднородное сочинение основ).

По форме написания можно определить семантику сложного прилагательного: водно-спасательная служба (водная спасательная служба), водноспортивный комплекс (для занятий водным спортом.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!Я и по учебнику учила,и на разных сайтах читала статьи на эту тему,но никак не могла определять.Про случай с подчинительной связью и однородного сочинения первый раз встретила,Вы мне очень помогли)

Answer (score 3):

> В каких случаях сложные прилагательные
> пишутся через дефис,а в каких слитно?

См. http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=70#pp70

Comment: Или подойдет учебник 6 класса